# Laravel - Query count values from last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a user access table and I want do a query that returns me the number of access by date.

My table has this columns:

```
id
type -> int
id_user -> int
created_at -> datetime
```

My database records:
[image]

I'm trying to this query:

```
    $admin = userAccess::distinct()
                  ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total ') , DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")'), DB::raw('DAYNAME(created_at) as dia'))
                  ->where('created_at', '>=', DB::raw('DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY'))
                  ->where('type', 1)
                  ->groupBy('created_at')
                  ->limit(7)
                  ->get();
```

With this query it returns me:

```
Monday(2018-10-08) -> 1
Tuesday(2018-10-09) -> 1
```

And the result that I want is:

```
Monday(2018-10-08) -> 3
Tuesday(2018-10-09) -> 1
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: For what you're doing wrong, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

try following the following 
you have to group by date eg: '2018-10-08' not the time stamp

```
$admin = userAccess::distinct()
                  ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total ') , DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as created_date '), DB::raw('DAYNAME(created_at) as dia'))
                  ->where('created_at', '>=', DB::raw('DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY'))
                  ->where('type', 1)
                  ->groupBy('created_date')
                  ->limit(7)
                  ->get();
```